# VF page for list button on Lightning Experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

I am working on a VF page to create an Opportunity from custom related List button on Opportunity itself. My requirement is to pre-populate some fields from original opportunity to child opportunity, which I am fine. However we also need to consider record type and show the stages as per record type. As I am querying the Original opportunity based on Id comes from URL, how can I restrict the stage values based on record type?

Class:

```
public class tenPageSizeExt {

    public List<Case> results {get;set;}
    public String filterId {get;set;}
    private Id accountId;

    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Open', 'Open'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Closed', 'Closed'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('All', 'All'));
        return options;
    }
    public Opportunity opp{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp2{get;set;}
    public Opportunity opp1{get;set;}
    public String oName{get; set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
    public tenPageSizeExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController qcontroller) {
    getItems();
        //controller.setPageSize(10);
        this.controller = qcontroller;
        Id parentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        opp1 =[SELECT Id,
                      Name,
                      StageName,
                      CloseDate,
                      Amount,
                      OwnerID,
                      Original_Opportunity__c,
                      Site__c,
                      Donor_Account__c,
                      Secondary_Opportunity_Owner__c,
                      Donor_Contact__c,
                      Payment_Contact__c,
                      Payment_Account__c,
                      Site_Location__c,
                      Budgeted__c, 
                      Soft_Payment_Credit__c,
                      Account_Soft_Payment_Credit__c,
                      CampaignId,
                      Honoree_Name__c,
                      Media_Campaign__c,
                      Probability,
                      Type,
                      Date__c,
                      Number_of_Times_Acknowledgement__c,
                      Donor_Advised_Fund__c
                      from Opportunity where Id=:parentId LIMIT 1];  
        opp2=New Opportunity();
        opp2.Name =opp1.Name+' Payment';
        opp2.StageName='Posted';
        opp2.Amount=opp1.Amount;
        opp2.CloseDate=opp1.CloseDate;
        opp2.Original_Opportunity__c=opp1.Id;
        opp2.Payment_Contact__c=opp1.Donor_Contact__c;
        opp2.Payment_Account__c =opp1.Donor_Account__c;
        opp2.OwnerID= opp1.OwnerID;   
        opp2.RecordtypeID= opp1.RecordtypeID;  
        opp2.Probability= 100;  

    }

     public PageReference InserrtOpp()
    {
        try{
        insert opp2;
        }catch(exception e)
        {
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,'my error msg '+ e);
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);

        }
        PageReference cancel = controller.cancel();
        controller.save();
        return cancel;
    }


}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

How can I show the Stage values only relevant to specific record type?

Comment: Is your button/page bypassing the recordtype selection screen? How is the StageName field currently being represented on the page?

Comment: Yes, it is bypassing the record type selection. Currently the picklist values are populating as per the default record type.

Comment: So, the screenshot is of opp2, and the StageName picklist is that of a sales process other than the one belonging to opp1's RecordType?

Comment: Yes, opp2 is new record and the StageName is belongs to opp1's recordtype.

Comment: Is there a way we can change the default record type for the VF page? may be a dumb question:)

Comment: So, you're setting opp2's Record Type to be the same as opp1's in your constructor. If you want opp2 to have a different record type (and its associated sales process), you should assign that record type to opp2, instead of just using opp1's. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code as posted is assigning opp1's record type to opp2. And so opp2 will use the Sales Process assigned to that record type. You need to assign the correct record type to opp2 in order for it to have the correct Sales Process.